# How can I replace every regex match with itself and some concatenations?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a console output that is a string `{x:0,y:0,width:1920,height:1080}` and need to convert it to object but I can't JSON.parse() it until all properties are surounded by quotes.

I managed to find this regex expression that will match with any word: `\b[\w]+\b` but I don't know how to use every match to replace `'"' + match + '"'` on both sides. I realized there are also numbers in there so maybe this would be a better regex: `\b[a-zA-Z]+\b` provided that property names never include numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a group (i.e.: enclose the pattern with `(` and `)`) and access it with `$1`:

```js
var out = "{x:0,y:0,WIDTH:1920,hEiGhT:1080}";

var rgx = /\b([a-z]+)\b/gi; // use the flag 'i' to make it case-insensitive

console.log(out.replace(rgx, '"$1"'));
```